# C++ what is better when trying to compare strings "==" or CString.Find()

Tags: c++

as the subject says.
in C++  what is better when trying to compare strings "==" or `CString.Find()?`
I have a mixed large application C++ and C# code.
I am not a C++ dev. but I can read and modify code as needed.
in C++ modules we use a lot of `if ( A ==_T("B") then {}` where "A" is CString type.
I have found that CString has a built in `.find` method and wonder if it is a better option to use.

thanks

Comment: For starters, in the several thousands of pages that make up the current C++ standard, there is no mention of anything called `CString`. Whatever this `CString` is, read the documentation for its `find` method, and for its `==` overload. Unless the two are identical -- and it's fairly likely that they're not -- since they do different things, which one is "better" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing `==` to [`CString::Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms928981.aspx) is not apples-to-apples: operator `==` checks for *equality*, while `Find` returns `true` when the second string is contained in the first one:

```
// A: "hello"
// B: "hell"
A == _T(B) // FALSE
A.Find(B)  // TRUE
```

As an alternative to `==` you can use [`CString::Compare`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms928971.aspx) method, and check if the result it returns is zero:

```
A.Compare(B) == 0 // FALSE
```

Comment: Note for the future: `CString::Compare` will be the equivalent of `<=>` when it comes in C++20

Comment: go it. I was looking for a thing to streamline the code to look better but it seams there is no way to do this.  good info to know though. thanks.